# MPI do process thread communication

Tags: mpi

I want do process thread communication using MPI. In other word, the message address is a `process index` and `thread index`.

The MPI provide us that:

`MPI_Send(const void *buf, int count, MPI_Datatype datatype, int dest, int tag, MPI_Comm comm)`

the MPI standard said that:

> Each thread can issue MPI calls; however, threads are not separately addressable: a rank in a send or receive call identifies a process, not a thread. A message sent to a process
>   can be received by any thread in this process.

But I want some thing like this:

`Send(const void *buf, int count, Datatype datatype, int dest_process_index, int dest_thread_index, int tag, Comm comm)`

How can we encapsulate MPI to implement that?

Any advice will greate help. Thanks for your time. :)

Comment: You can *encode* the thread index in the tag.

Comment: You mean that I can do a mapping that : `new_tag = mapping(usr_tag,src_thread_index,dst_thread_index)`. and using `new_tag` to call MPI function?

Comment: yep, that is the idea!